# Configuration database missing

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2016

My configuration database of SharePoint 2016 has gone missing. It's .mdf file is also not there which means somebody has removed that database. What can be done now? I am unable to run any application, Central Admin, etc
.

Comment: If you are certain about "someone deleting it", you'll likely want to start to prepare for a backup recovery. Hopefully there is a backup for your database server available. In not too distant future you'll probably want to investigate why and how this happened too.

Comment: No, it must have got removed right from sql server management studio.

Answer (score 3):

If configuration database is missing, thats mean you farm is down and now you have to two options.

1. Either Built a new farm

   - You have to take the backup of all content dbs
   - Install and configure SharePoint in a farm.( you have to uninstall the sharepoint as Config DB missing)
   - Create new web application and service application
   - Apply all the customization, authentication and other changes ( if any).
   - now mount the content database to web application and test it.
   - lastly, perform a backup of all your database.
2. Restore the Config DB from backup,

   - Make Sure recover point is as close as possible to the deletion time. if there is lag between deletion time and recovery time then you may see the orphan sites. i.e if Config DB was deleted at 7AM and your restore time is 4 am then u will see issue.

Answer (score 2):

If the database is neither present in SQL Server Management Studio nor on disk as .MDF file, you cannot recover from this disaster with SharePoint methods. You need to restore the ConfigurationDatabase from your last backup.